# How to calculate distance for FOV in three JS

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm working on resizing the FOV value dynamically while changing the screen sizes in three JS. Here I have found a calculation which works perfectly at any screen, but I no idea for the distance in FOV. Kindly let me know your suggestions.

```
    const distance = 1000;
    const diag = Math.sqrt((height * height) + (width * width));
    this.camera.fov = Math.atan((diag) / (3 * distance)) * (180 / Math.PI);
```

So, kindly help me out with the use of the distance value and to calculate the distance value dynamically to the screen size without giving a fixed range.

Comment: Yes @Rabbid76. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ratio of the Z-distance and the height of an object on the view at perspective projection ([`PerspectiveCamera`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/cameras/PerspectiveCamera.)) is:

```js
h_z_ratio = Math.tan(this.camera.fov/2.0 * Math.PI/180.0) * 2.0;
```

which is the same as

```js
h_z_ratio = this.camera.getFilmHeight() / this.camera.getFocalLength();
```

[image]